# Update ACF field when WooCommerce order status switched to "Processing"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I'm working with WooCommerce and Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) in WordPress, and I've encountered a peculiar issue when trying to automatically update a custom field (order_shipping_number) in a WooCommerce order. I have two different methods for updating this field when an order's status changes to "processing", but only one of them works, and I'm trying to understand why.

***Method 1: Direct Update (Not Working)***
I tried a straightforward approach where I hook directly into the woocommerce_order_status_processing action and update the field using ACF's update_field function:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'update_product_custom_field_', 10, 1 );
function update_product_custom_field_( $order_id ) {
    // Generate the shipping number using the order ID
    $shipping_number = 'SHIPPINGNUMBERTEST';

    // Update the custom field for the shipping number
 
    update_field( 'order_shipping_number', $shipping_number, $order_id );
    
}
```

This method seems logical, but it doesn't update the field in the WooCommerce order.

***Method 2: Using acf/save_post (Working)***
However, when I use a nested action hook with acf/save_post, it works:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'update_product_custom_field_');
function update_product_custom_field_( $order_id ) {
    add_action('acf/save_post', 'update_shipping_number');
}

function update_shipping_number( $order_id ) {
    $shipping_number = 'SHIPPINGNUMBERTEST';
    update_field( 'order_shipping_number', $shipping_number, $order_id );
}
```

With this method, the field updates as expected.

**My Question:**
Why does the second method using acf/save_post work, but the direct approach fails to update the field? Is there something specific about how ACF handles data saving in the context of WooCommerce orders that requires the acf/save_post hook?

Any insights or explanations would be greatly appreciated, as I'm trying to understand the underlying mechanics of ACF and WooCommerce interactions.

Comment: Have you verified if the field is actually updated, but is then reset back later? Given that method two works, it seems likely to me that your code does work, but is then reset. You could try changing the priority of the action to be later (ex: `999`).

Comment: @Caleb unfortunately that does not work, but you are on the right track. it seems  that the method works to save on woocommerce_order_status_processing but then WP save_post hook runs and saves over that with the old / empty value. I am not fully sure what to do at the moment

Comment: Suggest tracking down precisely where the value is reverted, and examine that code to see how to bypass or workaround.